# Developing in Android with Python 2.7

Tags: android, python, python-2.7

I want to develop a Android app using Python 2.7.
I read about it online but I couldn't find good answers, I saw [Kivy](http://kivy.org/#home). But I also saw a way to develop python [via google](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python).

I want to show a webpage (not sure if its going to be online or offline), in a app, without the user having to download anything except the app.

I saw [Webview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), but I coulnd't find how to implement it.

In short:

- **How do I develop a android app that shows a webpage with python 2.7, without the user having to download anything except the app.**

Comment: What do you mean 'show a webpage with python 2.7'? You want to run a webserver like flask on the device?

Comment: @inclement I want to show html/ a webpage that is already on the internet. So no server is involved in the app itself. I think webview does exactly what want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Kivy app that displays and manages a webview using something like https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Android-native-embedded-browser, though this requires some interaction with the java api (done via python as in the link) because we don't have a way to stream the webview content to a kivy widget.

A webview-only app is something kivy is not that well suited for, you might be better off learning to make a normal java app.